# Reusing a model for different objects

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have defined the following model:

```
App.Node = DS.Model.extend({
    type: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

The data for this model can be retrieved via `REST` in `api/nodes`.

Now I have similar data which can be found in `api/phonenumbers`. The structure of the data is the same, so I wanted to reuse the model. I have defined:

```
App.Phonenumber = App.Node;
```

But this is not working. The request is still being sent to `api/nodes` for this model. Why? How can I reuse models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think `App.Phonenumber = App.Node.extend({});` might do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Can you ask 'Is Phonenumber a Node?' In your context?

If yes, than extension is your solution.

If not, then you probably can ask 'Does a Phonenumber resemble a Node?'.

In that case, I would do the following:

```
var genericNameConfig = {
  type : DS.attr('string'),
  name : DS.attr('string')
};

App.Node        = DS.Model.extend(genericNameConfig);
App.Phonenumber = DS.Model.extend(genericNameConfig);
```